# What language are SE Data Explorer queries written in?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I want to write a query for the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not sure which language I need to learn in order to do so. At a glance it looks a bit like SQL, but I'm not entirely sure.

What language are SE Data Explorer queries written in?

Comment: Strongly related: [Data Explorer syntax or language reference?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/137175)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), **queries are written in [Transact-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).**

> **A Quick Introduction to Data Explorer Queries**
>
> Click the Compose Query button up there and start typing your **T-SQL**
> query. That's it, it's really that easy! If you're not the
> query-writing type, you can still make use of all of the
> community-created queries, or check out the query tutorial for some
> help on how you can get started.

[Thanks to animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298977/what-language-are-se-data-explorer-queries-written-in?noredirect=1#comment971747_298977) for pointing me towards the help page.